# Assign dictionary values to specific columns based on dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to assign dictionary values to specific columns based on dictionary keys

I have an empty dataframe (countries_df) with only column headers:

**| esp | eng | mex | ger |**

And a have a dictionary where keys are matching column names:

{'esp': 'David',
'eng': 'Adam',
'mex': 'Jose'}

I need pass value from dictionary to dataframe and store inside columns where column name is equal to key. And if dictionary does not contain key from column names then just pass Null

In the end, it should look like this:

| esp | eng | mex | ger |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | Adam | Jose |  |

```
row=[]
for k,l in names.items():
        for column in countries.columns:
            if k == column:
                row.append(l)
            else: pass
    countries_df.loc[len(countries_df.index)] = row
    i+=1
```

It works good if dictionary has 4 keys and df has 4 columns. But in other cases i get "cannot set a row with mismatched columns" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `concat` which can handle missing/extra keys in the `names` dictionary

```
pd.concat([countries_df, pd.DataFrame([names])])
```

---

```
     esp   eng   mex  ger
0  David  Adam  Jose  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the first row and then added the new row to it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'esp': ['Moses'],
                   'eng': ['Gabriel'],
                  'mex': [None],
                  'ger': ['Stephan']})
row = {'esp': 'David', 'eng': 'Adam', 'mex': 'Jose'}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([row], columns=row.keys())], axis = 0)
df


     esp      eng   mex      ger
0  Moses  Gabriel  None  Stephan
0  David     Adam  Jose      NaN
```